# How to fill null values in pandas dataframe, with values from another column in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to fill the null values in `City` column based on `Country` column. If the country is same then it should fill the `NaN` value with the **frequent** city name corresponding to the country.

Input:

```
ID      City            Country
0       New York            USA
1            NaN            USA
2         London            UK
3         Mumbai            IND
4         Sydney            AUS
5            NaN            AUS
6         Sydney            AUS
7         Brisbane          AUS
```

Output:

```
ID      City            Country
0       New York            USA
1       New York            USA
2         London            UK
3         Mumbai            IND
4         Sydney            AUS
5         Sydney            AUS
6         Sydney            AUS
7         Brisbane          AUS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is replace possible empty strings to `NaN`s and then replace values of group by first non `NaN`s values:

```
df['City'] = (df.groupby('Country')['City']
                .transform('first'))
```

Or forward and back filling missing values:

```
df['City'] = (df.groupby('Country')['City']
                .transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()))
```